# Drive out a fly

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that means similar to driving out (a fly), so you 've got a fly or a bird flown into your home and you want to chase it out. It sounds like swish or woosh something. Does Anyone have any idea?

Comment: You can try to ***shoo*** it out of the house.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***[shoo](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shoo)***, though it means to chase *away* as opposed to *out*, especially in the sense of scattering pests as opposed to birds or bats which may have accidentally flown inside:

> *interj.* Used to frighten away animals or birds.
>      *tr.v.* To drive or frighten away by or as if by crying "shoo."

[AHD]. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shoo) calls it *A natural exclamation: first recorded in late Middle English. The verb use dates from the early 17th century.*

---

In American English (at least in the South), *shoo-fly* or *shoofly* is a term of its own; the Online Etymology Dictionary refers to it as an *[admonition to a pest](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=shoo)*.

*Shoo, fly* or *shoo-fly* are known from folk songs like *Shoo, Fly, Don't Bother Me* and *Skip to My Lou*, but have made their way into terms where the connection is unclear— a type of flask, a type of rocking horse, a type of pipeline or railroad, a type of punch. Most of these are associated with the South, though the most famous, *[shoofly pie](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1998-08-05/entertainment/9808050319_1_pie-shell-molasses-cake)*, 
is closely associated with the Amish, who are concentrated in Pennsylvania and Ohio. One theory is that the molasses in the pie attracts flies, who must be shooed away; as it is a pie of molasses and crumbs, however, *shoofly* became associated with something temporary or makeshift.

Comment: I think this is closer to what OP wanted than swat.

Answer (score 1):

You can *swat* a fly (this fits with your "swish" and "woosh" idea). It doesn't necessarily imply though that you're tying to chase the fly away--it can also imply that you're trying to kill the fly.